# UIBezierPath can't change the color of the line

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, uibezierpath

This is my code

```
 func  drawSmallCircles(){
        for oneArray in points {
            let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[0]))
            let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[1]))
            let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
                endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
                clockwise: true)
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(55), green: CGFloat(37), blue: CGFloat(23), alpha: CGFloat(1))
            path.fill()

            color.setFill()


            path.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
            path.stroke()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

as you see, i am having a custom color. my problem is that the color always black.

see

[image]

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
                self.opaque = false;
              drawSmallCircles()


        }
```

this is the drawRec for me

#### Update1

after Rob answer, this is my code

```
  let points = [[270, 290],[300, 320],[330, 350],[0, 20],[30, 50],[60, 80],[90, 110],[120, 140],[150, 170],[180, 200],[210, 230],[240, 260]]
 func  drawSmallCircles(){
        for oneArray in points {
            let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[0]))
            let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[1]))
            let radius: CGFloat = 50.0
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(100), y: CGFloat(100)),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
                endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
                clockwise: true)
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(55/255), green: CGFloat(37/255), blue: CGFloat(23/255), alpha: CGFloat(1))
         //   path.fill()
            color.setStroke()
            path.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
            path.stroke()
//            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            self.opaque = false;
          drawSmallCircles()


    }
```

but still the same black color,

i did what you said and i called the setStock method on the color and i changed the colors values to 0 between 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the documentation for [`initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:), it points out that those should be values between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Furthermore, you never call `setStroke` to set the line color. You call `color.setStroke()` to set the color, and then call `path.stroke()` to draw the stroke at the previously specified color.

--

You might want something like:

```
func  drawSmallCircles(){
    for oneArray in points {
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[0]))
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[1]))
        let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngleRadiant, endAngle: endAngleRadiant, clockwise: true)
        let color = UIColor(red: 55.0/255.0, green: 37.0/255.0, blue: 23.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        color.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Note, that's a pretty dark color, so it might look black. You might want to lighten that up (using a few values closer to `1.0`) to see the color more clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95394/discussion-between-rob-and-sarah).

Comment: @Rob: It's not rounding to zero. With integer division the result **is** zero in this case.

Comment: @TomHarrington - Yes, I know. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Please help me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927854/terminating-since-there-is-no-system-app you are the only one that could know these stuff