# Terminating since there is no system app

Tags: ios, swift

this error is driving me crazy.

i have a button, and i want to move to a view controller. (i can open that view controller if i set it as an initial view controller), but now i am calling it from a button click.

the view controller contains a custom view, i put a break point, on the draw rect, and when the draw rect finishes, the simulator terminated, and i got this message on the screen.

```
XPC connection interrupted
Terminating since there is no system app.
```

i updated my xcode to the last version, i tried to add a navigation , but nothing helped, i kept with this excpetion. please help me,

the code that i am using to open the view controller is

```
let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WaitingViewController") as! WaitingViewController2
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

on a button click, and as i said, it is already go to the view did load, but the excpetion happpens after the draw rect in my custom view though now i made that draw rect empty.

#### Note

i am using the exact same code to move from one view controller to another one that don't have a custom view and it works

i have these functions inside my custom view (maybe the error is not here, but i am trying to put you in the situation, i don't know where is it)

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    //    super.drawRect(rect)
        //if isFirst {
        //  self.opaque = false;
    //    drawSmallCircles()
        //isFirst = false
        //}


    }
```

**please don't make that question as duplicated, because if you do, that sound you never ever read that question, please look into it, the question says that it found a WORK ARROUND, by change the method navigation, i don't have that method from the first place.**

#### that question doesn't even have an answer

Comment: Show us some code, we don't have enough info to say anything

Comment: @Peyman i add some code for u

Comment: Does error go away when you comment out **drawRect** func? not just the inside but the entire function. Don't provide drawRect is what I'm saying.

Comment: @Peyman yes even when i comit the drawrect at all, like i deleted it. the error still

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684157/xpc-connection-interrupted-in-xcode-7-for-ios-9

Comment: @Peyman i already did, but actually it doesn't have an answer

Comment: @Peyman did you mark that quesiton as duplicate?

Comment: no. it seems like it's an xcode bug. I can't reproduce it and I couldn't find a lot on it so can't help